# BIND: Redundant Master Nameservers

Tags: dns, bind

So I've googled around and can't find anything related to this. Clearly it has to happen though. I can't imagine organizations that don't have redundant master servers. The common approach I've found on google is to make redundant the slave servers, but that doesn't address the fact that if a master fails, a slave only works correctly so long.

I have a a set of DNS servers in my lab network. One master, two slaves, two recursive-only servers.

The master does zone file transfers to the slaves, and is hidden. It does not accept queries or allow recursion, designed according to best practice documents I found on the Internet.

The slaves allow queries from the recursive-only servers, which have forwarders set to my ISP DNS, and the local slaves (for internal network resolution of VMs and such).

I'm planning on setting up another master server, to enable high availability,

How do I go about doing this with BIND? I know I can set `masters { server1; server2; };` in the configuration for the slaves, but how do I deal with having two masters?

1. If there conflicts in the zone files between two masters, who takes precedence when transferring to the slaves?
2. How do I define failover? If Master1 fails the slaves will automatically try the second IP listed in the `masters` field, correct? So I shouldn't need to set anything up to have automatic failover?

EDIT: Here is a visual of my current setup: (I'd like to add one more master server)

[image]

Comment: "But that doesn't address the fact that if a master fails, a slave only works correctly so long." Your case just show the traditional update mechanism using DNS UPDATE/AXFR/IXFR messages. However you are completely free to configure all of your nameservers completely out of band. For example using rsync. In that way, you have a "distribution" box that has the data and it is pushed in some way to all nameservers. In that case there are no master/slaves anymore (a deprecated terminology now) all are the same, like clones.

Answer (score 3):

In case of dual master, each one behaves independently, do you want zones to be kept in sync.

There is no master that takes precedence. The parent DNS servers typically (and are expected to) randomize/rotate the order the nameservers for zones are presented in, and client software typically queries this in order they were received. (This might not be the case for some corner cases - I surmise where the parent is controlled and/or routing can be manipulated in conjunction with a CDN/multicast traffic)

To do this you simply configure each server as a master, and don't have any "masters" line. I use a script to push out identical updates to masters.

You don't need to set up failover. The DNS clients will sequentially try nameservers if they don't get a response. That said, this is far from ideal to rely on clients as it very noticeably slows DNS response times where the first server does not respond.  Longer TTLs on SOA records can partially mitigate this.

As such, no master takes precedence, they are treated identically , although you might be able to weight this behaviour with differing ttls for the SOA record and different serial - but I'd advise against this as it might cause issues. I've never tried it, so I'm speaking theoretically based on the understanding I got while learning this 20 years ago and subsequent practical experience running dual master servers.

Comment: How are the slaves going to receive zone transfers if I don't have a masters line in their config file? Keeping zones up to date with both masters isn't an issue, we have configuration management for that. DNS clients won't be hitting the masters at all, they are specifically configured for zone transfers and only zone transfers. All load for responding to queries is delegated to the slaves. I'm more concerned with how the slaves are going to handle one of the masters going down.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in your question and didn't realise you were going to keep slaves (and I'm not sure I get the intricacies of the question).  You simply list the masters in the masters line. Have a look at https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01467/0/How-does-BIND-choose-the-master-for-a-zone-refresh-zone-timer-or-notify.html to see how this is handled.   As an aside, why not circumvent this complexity by moving to an all master configuration (possibly driven by a replicated database backend and something like powerdns)

Comment: Sorry for the misleading question. Okay, so if I understand your answer correctly, specifying in the slaves configuration files the two masters using the `masters` line automatically sets them up to work, with HA being provided by querying the next master on the list if the first one doesn't respond?

Comment: That sounds right. I've not done it though, so I can't verify from my knowledge.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I'm going to leave the question up to see if I can get a more specific response. Appreciate your help though.

Comment: That's how an SE is meant to work.  I hope you can find your answer. (But would moving this to serverfault se get you more qualified people looking at it?)

Comment: Technically since this is for a personal lab at home and not a business environment (event though I'm trying to replicate production usage) I think it would against serverfault's rules. Maybe Unix&Linux SE though.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you put the second DNS master as the *slave* of your primary master DNS? I have a DNS infrastructure with 2 DNS masters, and the second one is a slave, it also get all the zones from the primary DNS, and the other "real" slaves have 2 masters, considering the second master as a master and not a slave. This means you need to allow the second master to transfer zones, even if it isn't defined as a master inc config file.